# Combination of monolog handlers seems not to work

Tags: symfony, monolog

i'm struggling with a monolog configuration for quite some time and hope you can help me.

I want my application to log

1) evrything from notice upward

2) but in case of an error all available logs (or if possible only for info upward all logs).

This is how i though it might work: collecting logs from *fingers_crossed* AND a *stream*, deduplicate them and send them to syslog

```
handlers:
    filter_for_errors:
        type: fingers_crossed
        action_level: error
        handler: unique

    standard:
        type: stream
        level:  notice
        handler:  unique
        formatter: monolog.formatter.session_request

    unique:
        type: deduplication
        handler:  log2Syslog

    log2Syslog:
        type: syslog
        facility: local5
        ident: shop
        formatter: monolog.formatter.session_request
        level:  info
```

Does one of you see my error or has deeper knowledge about what handlers can be combined and which not?

At the moment i see only error log lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a **group** handler.

```
# app/config/config_prod.yml
monolog:
handlers:
    main:
        type:         fingers_crossed
        action_level: critical
        handler:      grouped
    grouped:
        type:    group
        members: [streamed, deduplicated]
    streamed:
        type:  stream
        path:  '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
        level: debug
    deduplicated:
        type:    deduplication
        handler: swift
    swift:
        type:       swift_mailer
        from_email: 'error@example.com'
        to_email:   'error@example.com'
        subject:    'An Error Occurred! %%message%%'
        level:      debug
        formatter:  monolog.formatter.html
        content_type: text/html
```

More info here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_email.html

https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md

> **GroupHandler**: This handler groups other handlers. Every record
>   received is sent to all the handlers it is configured with.

Comment: Thx for your answer, St0iK.

As far as i understand your solution, you are collecting your logs from the fingers_crossed handler and spread them via group handler to a filelog and (deduplicated) email.

What i need is combine a stream and the fingers_crossed handler, deduplicate the rows generated from both sources and send them to syslog (or filelog or what ever). I don't see, how the group handler can help there?